# Windows 10 mute not working once fully logged in

Tags: windows-10, audio, mute

I have a strange issue - pressing the mute button on the keyboard, or selecting mute in the Windows volume control doesn't work. When I do that, it very briefly (for a fraction of a second) shows the volume to be muted (both the keyboard light and the windows display), then un-mutes immediately. However, I've discovered that before login, and for a short time after login, it works as expected. Once everything has started up, the problem begins. I've tried disabling some services, particularly anything with Lenovo, Thinkpad or audio, but to no avail. I'm running Creators update, fully updated as of time of posting, and all drivers updated.

Comment: Did you try with volume mixture dialog box?

Comment: @Biswa - not until you suggested it; but that didn't work either. However, it did point me to the fact eventghost was running, and had a profile that was causing this.

Comment: Restarting the `Windows Audio` service fixes this, but only till the next reboot. I have the same problem and I don't have EventGhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was due to EventGhost - there was a profile that was causing this. I believe it was in the default settings, and I hadn't disabled it.